# Changing Maps API styling depending on condition

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've got the following map as a base. It's a pretty regular map.

```
  function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 2,
      center: {lat: 23.9096187, lng: -29.6761281},
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
      disableDefaultUI: true
    });
  }
```

However! I want to implement these styles if a certain condition is true (e.g. if var temp > 80, add this styling). Is this possible?

```
 {
    stylers: [
      {hue: '#890000'},
      {visibility: 'simplified'},
      {gamma: 0.5},
      {weight: 0.5}
    ]
  },
  {
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{visibility: 'off'}]
  },
  {
    featureType: 'water',
    stylers: [{color: '#890000'}]
  }
], {
  name: 'Custom Style'
  });
var customMapTypeId = 'custom_style';

  map.mapTypes.set(customMapTypeId, customMapType);
  map.setMapTypeId(customMapTypeId);
```

Comment: You can certainly change the style dynamically.  What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the map style to your defined style at any time by calling:

```
map.setOptions({
  styles: [{
    stylers: [{
      hue: '#890000'
    }, {
      visibility: 'simplified'
    }, {
      gamma: 0.5
    }, {
      weight: 0.5
    }]
  }, {
    elementType: 'labels',
    stylers: [{
      visibility: 'off'
    }]
  }, {
    featureType: 'water',
    stylers: [{
      color: '#890000'
    }]
  }]
});
```

Assumes that `map` is in scope (either make it global, or create the function that changes it in the scope of your initMap function since `map` is currently lolocal to that function).

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/wjt1gw00/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var toggle = true;
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("btn"), 'click', function() {
    if (toggle) {
      map.setOptions({
        styles: [{
          stylers: [{
            hue: '#890000'
          }, {
            visibility: 'simplified'
          }, {
            gamma: 0.5
          }, {
            weight: 0.5
          }]
        }, {
          elementType: 'labels',
          stylers: [{
            visibility: 'off'
          }]
        }, {
          featureType: 'water',
          stylers: [{
            color: '#890000'
          }]
        }]
      });

    } else {
      map.setOptions({
        styles: []
      });
    }
    toggle = !toggle;
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="change style" />
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yep, a few things I realized:

1 - All styles and dynamic edits to the map need to be within the original initMap() function.

2 - Needed to setup the different styles (with unique style IDs) and have the if/else statement set the map.setMapTypeId.